# AngularJS updating ng-repeat via input not working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I'm trying to update values in a ng-repeat on a ng-model;

I have the current directive:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function () {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div ng-repeat="e in model"><input ng-model="e"/></div>',
    scope: { 
      ngModel: '='
    },
    link: function($scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
      $scope.$watch(function (){
          return ngModelCtrl.$modelValue; 
      }, function (v) {
          $scope.model = ngModelCtrl.$viewValue;
      });
    }
  };
});
```

but it isn't updating the value as illustrated here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/E89sbXY0gUw53EmJobz0?p=preview

anybody knows what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://plnkr.co/edit/2JwxNzBRQa1dzACoJIpF?p=preview

Had to replace `$scope.model = ngModelCtrl.$viewValue;` with `scope.model = ngModelCtrl.$viewValue;` and it works fine.

```
app.directive('myDirective', function () {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div ng-repeat="e in model"><input ng-model="e"/></div>',
    scope: { 
      ngModel: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
      console.debug()
      scope.$watch(function (){
          return ngModelCtrl.$modelValue; 
      }, function (v) {
          scope.model = ngModelCtrl.$viewValue;
      })
    }
  };
});
```

**UPDATE**: I converted 'stuff' to an array of objects and now it works:

http://plnkr.co/edit/2JwxNzBRQa1dzACoJIpF?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.stuff = [{number: 1},{number: 2},{number: 3}];
});

app.directive('myDirective', function () {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div ng-repeat="e in model"><input ng-model="e.number"/></div>',
    scope: { 
      ngModel: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
      console.debug()
      scope.$watch(function (){
          return ngModelCtrl.$modelValue; 
      }, function (v) {
          scope.model = ngModelCtrl.$viewValue;
          console.log(scope.model)
      })
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Euhm, sorry apparently forgot to save that, but the problem isn't showing the inputs, it's updating the values, on your example that problem exists as well

Comment: @kukkuz you must have used `ngModelCtrl.$render` rather than watching for changes

Answer (score 0):

@Kiwi ng-repeat creates a child scope and ng-model will use the property on the child scope, because ng-model binding will evaluate on the current scope. This is the reason why the json presented in the view doesn't change in your example as it was bound to a property on the child scope created by the ng-repeat directive.

Check this [simple jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/zb8pf8dm/1/) I hope it will be of help to you.

```
<div ng-app="demo">
  <div ng-controller="DefaultController as ctrl">
    {{ctrl.numbers | json}}    
    <numbers numbers="ctrl.numbers"></numbers>
  </div>
</div>


angular
  .module('demo', [])
  .controller('DefaultController', DefaultController)
  .controller('NumbersController', NumbersController)
  .directive('numbers', numbers);

  function DefaultController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.numbers = [1, 2, 3];
  }

  function numbers()
  {
    var directive = {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        numbers: '='
      },
      template: '<div ng-repeat="number in vm.numbers"><input type="number" ng-model="vm.numbers[$index]"/></div>',
      bindToController: true,
      controller: NumbersController,
      controllerAs: 'vm'
    };

    return directive;
  }

  function NumbersController() {
    var vm = this;
  }
```